# Typescript gives errors even when code is fixed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm

I had a typo and called upon `green[4500]`, which doesn't exist (in Material UI, but that's not important) instead of `green[500]`, which does.

So I got a typescript error because `Property '4500' does not exist on type`... whatever the type of `green`. is.

Then I fixed it, and saved it, and I still get the error. Even the error has the fixed code, but the error remains.

```
Property '4500' does not exist on type '{ 50: "#e8f5e9"; 100: "#c8e6c9"; 200: "#a5d6a7"; 300: "#81c784"; 400: "#66bb6a"; 500: "#4caf50"; 600: "#43a047"; 700: "#388e3c"; 800: "#2e7d32"; 900: "#1b5e20"; A100: "#b9f6ca"; A200: "#69f0ae"; A400: "#00e676"; A700: "#00c853"; }'. Did you mean '400'?  TS2551

     6 | 
     7 | const StartButton = styled(Button)({
  >  8 |   background: green[500],
       |                     ^
     9 |   color: 'white'
    10 | })
    11 | const StopButton = styled(Button)({
```

Restarting the server fixes it, not very surprisingly. I'm using WebStorm and running the server from the run menu (not directly from a terminal) if that makes any difference.

Why is Typescript behind?

Comment: Does the error remain in the editor as well? Are you using `tsc` directly or via webpack? Please check if you have `Backup files before saving` enabled in the IDE Preferences | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings. If yes, try disabling it and see it the server works better.